# Need help on program that uses facebook/instagram info

Tags: python, html, facebook, web, instagram

A client wants to have information about public instagram/facebook profiles (photos/videos published, total likes/comments) from a period of time. How do I go about doing this?
I found out that some of that information is available in the website source code, but how do I use that information? Also is there any sites/services that does that already? The only ones I found only go as back as a few weeks, or only procress future posts.

I thought about automatizing the process with python, is it a good idea?

I'm new in programming, so any help is aprecciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Instagram is trying to limit as much as possible bot activities, I'm not sure about Facebook though.

You can definitely try to webscrape (using python or other tools) the information you need but if things don't work, it may not be your fault.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape.